# Anyone know why Polymer's core-scroll-header-panel isn't working in iOS?

Tags: polymer

So I have been designing a simple site with Polymer that works fine on PC and Android but doesn't show up right on iOS at all. The text is plain and nothing works. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or is this an already known bug?
Here's the mockup I was making: http://poly-ani.droppages.com/tabs.html

Comment: Noticed your site doesn't work as expected on desktop Safari either. Might help you to download safari for Windows & debug there, little easier typically than debugging on iOS.

Comment: Thanks, @sfeast, downloading Safari now. will keep this updated

Comment: @sfeast did you try this on OSX? Because the latest Safari for Windows was released in May 2012 and doesn't seem compatible with Polymer at all, their website does not even work properly

Comment: Ah didn't realize that. Yes I was trying on OSX, so guess that's not going to be too helpful.. In that case, I'll take a deeper look at your site later today & see if I can help further.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, but just took a few minutes to look at your code & seeing multiple issues. I don't have time to debug all this so instead I've created a jsbin here - http://jsbin.com/kebolakewi - which provides you with an easily editable template of one of the standard core-scroll-header samples. I recommend starting from here & modifying it to what you want. Then if you run into trouble, come back to this question & let us know. This way we can more easily collaborate on your code & have a known working place to start from. Should be much easier!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you so much @sfeast, I'll check out the jsbin now

Comment: Not the best looking website, but it all seems to work on Safari desktop 6.1.6

Comment: it looks like 0.5.1 fixed some issues I was having. works on iOS 7 & 8 now :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue now :( 

Its not working on iOS and I have <!DOCTYPE html> up top ... I checked on safari in the mac desktop as well and it doesnt work there either.

Comment: It works on android via stock chrome though. just not on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the doctype at the very top of your page!  iOS will not render properly without it.  I spent hours tearing my hair out on this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```